# Numbers change when using write.file()

Tags: r

I am trying to use the write.table() function in R to write an output. It has 3 columns, first has numbers, the second has a color indicator (#000000) and the third one has a number again. Simple enough right?

Well, when I run my script step by step, the output is the desired one, something like this:

> Tip ID Color Track    Cluster ID
>
> 13298267   #FF0000 1

But when I try to do it through command line, with exactly the same number and the same arguments, I get something like this:

> 13298267 #FF0000 156

I tried changing the encoding and nothing happened, I tried changing the third column as a number instead of an integer. Nothing

Does someone have any idea of what might be happening?

Comment: [Reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is always welcome.

Comment: Check the class of the Cluster ID (with str() ) - maybe its a factor and not numeric?

Comment: I am not really sure about how to do a reproducible example in this case...

Comment: Thanks @MarkeD, I checked before but not after doing the matrix, and you were right, it was converted to factor.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens if the class of the object is a factor, and not the expected numeric.  This is because the print() functions for factors and numerics will both output an (often different) number at a casual glance.

Best way to avoid it is to always check using str() what classes your objects are.